# How to save spinner and edit text on internal storage and pass it onto another activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to collect user input in an edit text view and a spinner and save the values to internal storage, then pass it on to another view but my activity crashes after click on my save button, I would appreciate if someone could look at my codes, and tell me what i am doing wrong.

**My user details saving activity**

```
public class PasswordKeeperActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

// initialise
EditText username, password, note;
Button save, reset;
public String savedata = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

String[] countryNames={"Google", "Yahoo", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Instagram", "BBM", "Skype", "Other"};
int flags[] = {R.drawable.google, R.drawable.yahoo, R.drawable.facebook, R.drawable.twitter, R.drawable.instagram, R.drawable.bbm, R.drawable.skype, R.drawable.other};

private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
// for inflating the menu
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// on selection of the menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.view_passwords:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PasswordView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    initialise();

   //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on 
   it
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
   flags, countryNames);
    spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    //to set the site Edit Text to get the focus




    // save the data to the textfile
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // creates hidden directory if not existing
            File dir = new File(getCacheDir(), "/sk/");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            // saving data part
            String sFileName = getCacheDir() + "/sk/logp.csv";
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);

                String  countryNames, sUser, sPass, sAdd;

                countryNames =
                sUser = username.getText().toString();
                sPass = password.getText().toString();
                sAdd = note.getText().toString();



                if ((sUser.equals("")) && (sPass.equals("")) && 
        (sAdd.equals(""))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter At least 
        one Field",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    if (sUser.equals(""))
                        sUser = "null";
                    if (sPass.equals(""))
                        sPass = "null";
                    if (sAdd.equals(""))
                        sAdd = "null";


                    // encrypting the passwords before saving
                    SimpleCrypto mcrypt = new SimpleCrypto();
                    sPass = SimpleCrypto.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt(sPass) );
                    //sPass = SimpleCrypto.encrypt("fugly", sPass);




                    writer.append(sUser);
                    writer.append(',');

                    writer.append(sPass);
                    writer.append(',');
                    writer.append(sAdd);

                    writer.append('\n');

                    // generate whatever data you want

                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password Saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(PasswordKeeperActivity.this, 
        PasswordView.class);
                    String[] myStrings = new String[] {"Google", "Yahoo", 
       "Facebook", "Twitter", "Instagram", "BBM", "Skype", "Other"};
                    int logo[]  = new int[] {R.drawable.google, 
       R.drawable.yahoo, R.drawable.facebook, R.drawable.twitter, 
       R.drawable.instagram, 
       R.drawable.bbm, R.drawable.skype, R.drawable.other};
                    intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);
                    intent.putExtra("logos", logo);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    // Reset
    reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            countryNames.equals("Google");
            note.setText("");
            username.setText("");
            password.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Field(s) Cleared!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}



public void initialise() {


    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonReset);
}

/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 *
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to 
 grant permissions
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 
   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
}
```

**my log**

```
08-15 10:02:44.353 5961-5961/com.com.dreacot.dreacot.fingerprint E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.com.dreacot.dreacot.fingerprint, PID: 5961
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                                                                                   at com.dreacot.fortpasswordkeeper.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:35)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6330)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**then my custom list adapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] countryNames;
private final int flags[];

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] countryNames, int flags[]) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, countryNames);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.countryNames=countryNames;
    this.flags=flags;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(countryNames[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(flags[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+countryNames[position]);
    return rowView;

}
}
```

**edit**

the password view

```
    ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpass);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
     int logo[] = intent.getIntArrayExtra("logo");
    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, myStrings, logo);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem= myStrings[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the code where you instantiate the CustomListAdapter class and how you get the params from intent ?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Attempt to read from null array (CustomListAdapter.java:35), does it concern "countryNames" or "flags" array ?

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(flags[position]); according to my log that is the line with the problem in custom list adapter

Comment: Can you just fix your array definition int logo[] in int[] logo everywhere in your code, just in case ?

Comment: alright just a sec

Comment: ok I got it see my answer !

Comment: still the same crash log

Comment: There might be another problem and that is you are passing arguments in wrong order while initialising the adapter.

Comment: @AshutoshSagar what do you mean?

Comment: while setting adaptor you pass like `CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
   flags, countryNames);` but in its constructor its like this `public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] countryNames, int flags[])`. So what I meant is replace positions of `flags` and `countryNames`.

Comment: i get an error that way

Comment: @MoraS. Hey there, could you please take a look at my recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695005/how-do-i-display-an-item-saved-using-filewriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled your key for getting your value from Intent.

```
intent.getIntArrayExtra("logo")
```

Instead of

```
intent.getIntArrayExtra("logos")
```

To avoid this you'd better using a constant like:

```
public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_KEY_LOGOS = "logos"
```